# If cosecant is $\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$ why do $\sin^{-1}(1)$ and $\frac{1}{\sin(1)}$ give different answers?

Tags: trigonometry

When I go $\sin^{-1}(1)$ I get $90$ degrees but when I put $\frac{1}{\sin(1)}$ in the calculator I get $57.2$ degrees. Why is this?

Comment: $\sin^{-1}x$ is the inverse trigonometric function which gives you the angle $\theta$ for which $\sin\theta=x$

Comment: $$\sin^{-1}x\neq \dfrac{1}{\sin x}$$

Comment: Actually, a better notation is $\arcsin(x)$ instead of $\sin^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: So, should I put this as an answer, or are the comments enough?

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 4):

$\sin^{-1}(x)$ is confusingly defined, not as $\frac 1{\sin(x)}$ but as the inverse function, the angle $\theta$ such that $\sin (\theta)=x$ (with restrictions to make it a proper function).  So $\sin^{-1}(1)$ is the angle with sine of 1, which is $90^\circ$.   But if you compute $\sin(1^\circ)$ you get about $0.017452$ and the inverse of this is about $57.2$.  Note this is not degrees, it is a pure number.  It is numerically close to $\frac {180}\pi$ because for $x \ll 1$ in radians, $\sin x \approx x$, so $\sin 1^\circ=\sin (\frac \pi{180})$radians $\approx \frac \pi{180}$